# How to select checked checkboxes and add their values in C#?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a list of checkboxes and I need to tell which are checked using `C#`. How would I tell which individual checkboxes are checked and then add their values together? I am using `Asp.Net Core`, if that could be helpful

```html
<div class="row">
    <form method="post" class="offset-3 col-5 border">
        <div id="Colors" class="form-group" type="checkbox">
            <label class="form-check-label">Colors</label>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input id="Red" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1">
                <label class="form-check-label">Red</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input id="Yellow" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="2">
                <label class="form-check-label">Yellow</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input id="Green" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="4">
                <label class="form-check-label">Green</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input id="Blue" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="8">
                <label class="form-check-label">Blue</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Post" class="btn btn-primary" />               
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Start by giving them a name

Comment: Im rather new to this, what would naming them do for me?

Comment: @HassanMonjezi Thanks a bunch for the link, that helped me greatly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Jquery` and you want to get all checkboxses are checked then you can do what you need like below :

```
    var selected = [];
$('.form-check-input input:checked').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

if you are using another `Javascript` librarry, you should do same.

if you want to get them in your Controller, so you should follow these steps:

1- Add a name to your Checkbox like (here chose `color`) :

```
<input id="Red" class="form-check-input" name="color" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

2- Add a property to your Model

```
public class AddPostModel
{
    public List<int> Color { get; set; }
}
```

In this way, when you post your view, you have all values from checkboxes are checked.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Is there some way I can call this from within my C# controller code?

Comment: @Bubinga check answer update